# Android's viewGroup.removeAllViews() is extremely slow, any alternative?

Tags: android, viewgroup, removeall

Traceviewing my code in `ddms` I found out that `ViewGroup.removeAllViews()` seems pretty slow when applied to a linearlayout (1sec for 40 items). Is there any alternative to empty my layout?

details:

```
ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindows () V 75%
View.dispatchDetachedFromWindows () V 25%
```